# Why "seen" instead of "saw"

Tags: grammar, verbs

In instagram, when someone see the message, there's a little indicator "**seen**" that tells you that the person you are chatting with has seen your message. My question is why it is "**seen**" written instead of "**saw**" in place of indicator? Because saw is a simple past verb and seen is past participle used with have/has, and cannot be used idependently, right?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to indicate why you think the word should be ***saw*** and not *seen*? Note that you actually use *seen* in your explanation.

Comment: Short for “has been seen”. Describes the *state* of the message. “Saw” cannot apply to the *state* of the message.

Comment: I agree with @Anton's interpretation. Another is that "seen" is an adjective describing the message.

Comment: Neither 'seen' nor 'saw' is a complete sentence. However, 'seen' is an acknowledged shorthand way of writing '[This] message has been seen'; 'saw' would be headlinese for 'The person you are communicating with [just] saw your message'. 'This message has been seen' is a far crisper original, and the headlinese reflects that, selecting 'seen'.

Comment: Nobody has mentioned that "seen" is also a participle and that is likely the form that is being used here. "Message seen" is a perfectly fine noun phrase to me.

Comment: OP also seems to think that past participles must appear with "to have", and that is not true: "The message, seen yesterday, shocked everyone."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only immediate subject available in a tag like "seen" is the message to which it is applied, and so the descriptor "seen" is really just the interesting part of the passive voice sentence "This message has been seen". It describes what has happened to the message.

To apply "saw" (active voice) would shift the focus to the reader of the message (the subject) rather than the message itself. But Instagram evidently thinks we are interested in the state of the message in this context, not the reader(s) of it. The list of readers is sometimes given as a list of passive agents, "Seen by ...".

Comment: The past active participle in English is "having seen" and that clearly wouldn't make sense here.